# Why doesn't Latin caseus have "w"?

Tags: latin

Why doesn't Latin caseus from *kwh₂et- have "w"?

Answer (score 4):

An intermediate **quaseus* is indeed hypothesized. Fay calls to compare with Plautus' *cassat=quassat* (Lewis and Short: *quasso* (old form *casso*, Plaut. Bacch. 2, 3, 71 Ritschl)).

He says (Fay and Ed, Greek and Latin Word Studies, The Classical Quarterly, Vol. 1, No. 1, 1907):

> The equation of caseus 'cheese' with O.B. kvasû  'fermentum' may be
> correct, but no valid inference, I think, can be drawn from it for the
> treatment of **kw-**. It does not demand discussion at this time when
> I am seeking to establish two negative conclusions, (I) that there is
> no good evidence to prove that **kw-* yields Greek *k*, Lat. *v-*; (2)
> and no good evidence for **k̂ w-** yielding Lat. *v-*; but I suspect
> that Plautine *cassat=quassat* gives us a right to regard caseus
> **quaseus*.  I  have small doubt that *cāsseus* (older form *cāseum*, neuter) is derived from from **lac quassum*, with suffix like the suffix
> of cereus and farreus. ...

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all certain that Lat. *cāseus* "cheese" derives from some such PIE root as *kwath₂- "boil" (this is the form of the root given in LIV, though both it and your *kwh₂et- look rather odd), precisely because of the phonetic difficulty you mention. De Vaan in his etymological dictionary does not accept the connection, and concludes that the etymology of *cāseus* is unknown.